# Bootstrap classes for specific breakpoints

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, class, bootstrap-4

I would like to know if there is a way to make a Boostrap class specific for a breakpoint.

I know there are some like `col-sm-2 col-md-4` etc.
But what I'm really looking for now would be for the *width* of an element.

Current code for *width 100%* : 
`className="w-100"`

I supposed there was some way to use something like `w-sm-100 w-md-75 w-lg-50` or `sm-w-100 md-w-75 lg-w-50` but I didn't find anything like this in Bootstrap documentation or anywhere else.

So, is there a simple way to do this or are we obliged to do it through media queries in css ?

Thank you !

Comment: https://dev.to/shhdharmen/responsive-size-classes-in-bootstrap-3ojl

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There was a time when I was also searching for the same issue and do not find the solution other than using `media query`.

So I decided to create a `CSS` project with the help of `media query` for different `width sizes` at different resolution based on `Bootstrap`.

So whenever I want to use something like this `w-sm-100 w-md-50 w-lg-25`, I can simply include my own created `stylesheet CDN Link` just after my `bootstrap CDN` link then I can use such `classes` like this.

Here is the link of stylesheet:

```css
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=1yTLwNiCZhIdCWolQldwq4spHQkgZDqkG">
```

Live Example:

```html
<!-- Bootstrap CDN link -->

<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<!-- My own Stylesheet CDN Link -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=1yTLwNiCZhIdCWolQldwq4spHQkgZDqkG">

<!-- HTML -->
<h1 class="w-xl-75 w-lg-100 w-md-50 w-sm-75 w-100 bg-primary">Hello World</h1>
```

The only disadvantage is that if you want to specify the property `w-md-50`, it will work only on `md` not on `xl` or `lg`.

So in order to make it work for devices greater than `md`.

You have to do like this:  `w-xl-50 w-lg-50 w-md-50`.

Comment: That's what I also thought doing when seeing there was nothing mentioning that on internet.
Thank you !

Comment: Getting 404 when sending request to google drive link

Comment: @ThenujanSandramohan, I have updated my `CSS` file drive link.

Answer (score 14):

If you want to do somthink like this :

```
<img class="w-100 w-md-50" src="..." alt="...">
```

You can do this by using a div and class "col" and "mx-auto" like this :

```
<div class="col col-md-6 mx-auto">
  <img class="w-100" src="..." alt="...">
</div>
```

Answer (score 12):

For Bootstrap 5. Add this to you variable-file and it'll do what you are describing.

```
@import "bootstrap/scss/functions";
@import "bootstrap/scss/variables";
@import "bootstrap/scss/utilities";

$utilities: map-merge( 
$utilities, ( "width": map-merge( 
map-get( $utilities, "width"), ( responsive: true ),),)
);
```

More info here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/api/#enable-responsive

Answer (score 4):

Actually, at Bootstrap 4, they specified and shown the [breakpoints](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/layout/overview/#responsive-breakpoints) they've used.

Using the same queries they've used, you can create a responsive class just by using the same format to easily understand it. Fareed's answer is great, but it can be improved upon.

Here's some of the snippet at the stylesheet I'm currently using:

```css
/* CUSTOM WIDTHS */
.w-10, .w-xs-10 { width: 10%!important; }
.w-15, .w-xs-15 { width: 15%!important; }
.w-20, .w-xs-20 { width: 20%!important; }

/* BREAKPOINTS */

/* SM breakpoint */
@media (min-width: 576px) {
    /* CUSTOM WIDTHS */
    .w-sm-10 { width: 10%!important; }
    .w-sm-15 { width: 15%!important; }
    .w-sm-20 { width: 20%!important; }
}

/* MD breakpoint*/
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    /* CUSTOM WIDTHS */
    .w-md-10 { width: 10%!important; }
    .w-md-15 { width: 15%!important; }
    .w-md-20 { width: 20%!important; }
}

/* LG breakpoint */
@media (min-width: 992px) {
    /* CUSTOM WIDTHS */
    .w-lg-10 { width: 10%!important; }
    .w-lg-15 { width: 15%!important; }
    .w-lg-20 { width: 20%!important; }
}
```

When used, it acts similar to bootstrap's responsiveness. For example:

```css
/* CUSTOM WIDTHS */
.w-10, .w-xs-10 { width: 10%!important; }
.w-15, .w-xs-15 { width: 15%!important; }
.w-20, .w-xs-20 { width: 20%!important; }

/* BREAKPOINTS */

/* SM breakpoint */
@media (min-width: 576px) {
    /* CUSTOM WIDTHS */
    .w-sm-10 { width: 10%!important; }
    .w-sm-15 { width: 15%!important; }
    .w-sm-20 { width: 20%!important; }
}

/* MD breakpoint*/
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    /* CUSTOM WIDTHS */
    .w-md-10 { width: 10%!important; }
    .w-md-15 { width: 15%!important; }
    .w-md-20 { width: 20%!important; }
}

/* LG breakpoint */
@media (min-width: 992px) {
    /* CUSTOM WIDTHS */
    .w-lg-10 { width: 10%!important; }
    .w-lg-15 { width: 15%!important; }
    .w-lg-20 { width: 20%!important; }
}
```

```html
<div class="w-md-20" style="background-color: black; color: white">20% at MD or above, but 100% less than that</div>
```